# How to remove the "explorer? bar" on vscode 1.35 new update

Tags: updates, gui, visual-studio-code, toolbar

I don't know what is this bar and why suddently appears with the new update. Can you help me disable it? Thx.

[image: new unknown bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the ["breadcrumb"](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_breadcrumbs) bar, which shows recent locations within the file (sections, functions, etc.)

It can be disabled through `breadcrumbs.enabled` or *View → Toggle Breadcrumbs*.